# jquery slideToggle switch out clicked element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to switch out the image clicked when using slidetoggle.

I have a link and a div below it. I am showing and hiding it and trying to change the image depending on whether or not the div has slide down or up.

```
<a href="#" id="login" src="membersignin2.png"><img src="/templates/stat/img/membersignin.png" alt="Member Sign in"></a>
<div id="loginDiv" style="display: none; "></div>
```

The jquery I have so far is

```
$('#login').click(function(){
    $('#loginDiv').slideToggle('slow',function(){
    })
})
```

How would I change out the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `src` attribute of the image:

```
$('#login img').attr('src','new source');
```

Or, you may want to add both images to your code, and hide/show them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

as the documentation for [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) says, this function slides one element out (if it's visible), or slides in, if it's hidden. so you're gonna first want to hide the image that's currently visible then show the other div (Also, you're gonna want to move the div IN the href, so the selector matches correctly)

```
$('#login').click(function(){

   $('#login img').slideToggle('slow',function(){///callback runs when animation ends
          $("#login #loginDiv").slideToggle("slow",function(){});
          // you use a empty callback because you don't need it for the second slideToggle
   })
   return false; // prevent default link action (so you don't have a extra hash in the URL)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#login').click(function(){
    $(this).contents('img').attr('src','path/to/new/img.jpg');
    $('#logindiv').slidetoggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```